# When do we add -NE when asking a question?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

There are some times that you use

> QUID EST

or

> UBI EST

Which I assume are known as a question starting point.

But then there are verbs that you add a NE at the end to make the other person know you are asking.

> AMBULABIMUSNE

Which I assume it means *Shall we walk?*

So when you want to combine QUID or UBI with this verb to say something like *Where shall we walk* do we say

> UBI AMBULABIMUSNE

Or

> UBI AMBULABIMUS

Comment: You probably want to say *quo ambulabimus* (where shall we walk to) rather than *ubi ambulabimus*. *Ubi* would be right if you were asking whether you want to take a walk at the mall or park, or the riverfront.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**We add *-ne***

**1.** when asking a yes-or-no question, that is to say, when we ask if a certain assertion is true or false, e.g.

> *Vides**ne** canem?* – Do you see the dog?

This is when we are asking neutrally. If we want to signal we are expecting or hoping for a negative answer, we can use the word *num*:

> *Num canem tetigisti?* – Did you really touch the dog? / Surely you did not touch the dog? etc.

Or, if we want to signal we are expecting a positive answer, we can use *nonne* (which is actually *non* + *-ne*):

> *Nonne canem vidisti?* – Did you not see the dog?

Simple *-ne* is neutral.

**2.** when asking for an alternative between two choices, where the “or” is always *an*:

> *Uter nostrum popularis est, tu**ne** an ego?* – Which one of us two is a man of the people, you or me?

You can also leave the *-ne* out in this case (*tu an ego*) or use the word *utrum*:

> *Utrum ea vestra an nostra culpa est?* – Is it your fault or ours?

Plot twist: To ask emphatically, you can also say *utrumne*, and *an* can be emphasized by saying *anne*.

By the way, all I just told you does not just apply to *direct* questions, but also to indirect questions, e.g.

> *Honestumne factu sit an turpe, dubitant.* - They are unsure whether it is an honourable or shameful thing to do.

**We do not add -ne** when we have a question word like *quid* or *ubi*.

Comment: Great answer! I think I'll make a separate post about what to do with _quid_ or _ubi_, assuming one doesn't already exist.

Comment: Just curious, is there a word for yes-or-no question in Latin?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1592/how-do-you-say-yes-and-no-in-classical-latin