# Is there an enclitic for non-binary questions?

Tags: syntax

The enclitic *-ne* is [used for binary questions](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16542/when-do-we-add-ne-when-asking-a-question) where you expect a yes or no answer. Does an enclitic exist for open-ended questions, like "where do you want to have dinner", or "who is that"?

Is this generally moot because the rest of the sentence indicates whether something is a question or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such enclitic, at least not a common one by any measure.
And what would you need it for?
If a question does not ask for a yes or a no, it has a specific question word indicating what is wanted: *quis, quando, cur, unde…*

As Sebastian says in his answer to the linked question: *-ne* is not used when we have a question word like *quid* or *ubi*.

Enclitics can be used in all questions:
*Ubi saltant maritus uxorque?*
The enclitic *-que* is used, but it does not indicate a question.
The only enclitic indicating a question is *-ne*.

As noted in Sebastian's answer, binary questions can be formed without *-ne*, using *nonne* or *num*.
But when the question is not binary, using *-ne* is not really an option.

Comment: I think it is a fair question, because in English we differentiate: “In what a city we live!” versus “In what a city do we live?” Does the first type of sentence exist in Latin?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I agree, the question is fair. I hope my answer didn't come across as condescending. For such a question-natured cry I think the best option is *o quam*, as in: *O quam amoena est urbs nostra!* Whether his works with *o* and other question words or without the *o* is not clear to me. Certainly worth exploring in a follow-up question.

Comment: I didn't take the answer negatively; I figured even though the answer was likely no it was worth asking in case someone else wondered and searched.

Comment: One of the things that got me thinking is that in Japanese you can [add _ka_ to the end of a sentence](https://selftaughtjapanese.com/2014/02/16/the-japanese-question-particle-か-ka/) like a sort of spoken question mark. Not an enclitic at all, but it got me wondering if there was something like that in Latin.

Comment: @Adam Finnish has an interrogative enclitic *-ko/-kö*, and it behaves very similarly to the Latin *-ne*. If there are small differences, I'm sure I'll replace all Latin rules with Finnish ones and never know about it. Germanic languages seem to have a tendency to indicate questions by word order. For any language student learning how questions work is a big question in learning the language in question.